# Cannot GET / error using express

Tags: node.js, express, graphql

I'm new to nodeJS, I'm trying to follow this [tutorial](https://medium.com/react-native-training/building-chatty-a-whatsapp-clone-with-react-native-and-apollo-part-1-setup-68a02f7e11).

My code:

```
// server/index.js
import express from 'express';
import { graphqlExpress, graphiqlExpress } from 'graphql-server-express';
import { makeExecutableSchema, addMockFunctionsToSchema } from 'graphql-tools';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { createServer } from 'http';
import { Schema } from './data/schema';
import { Mocks } from './data/mocks';
const GRAPHQL_PORT = 8000;
const app = express();
const executableSchema = makeExecutableSchema({
  typeDefs: Schema,
});
addMockFunctionsToSchema({
  schema: executableSchema,
  mocks: Mocks,
  preserveResolvers: true,
});
// `context` must be an object and can't be undefined when using connectors
app.use('/graphql', bodyParser.json(), graphqlExpress({
  schema: executableSchema,
  context: {}, // at least(!) an empty object
}));
app.use('/graphiql', graphiqlExpress({
  endpointURL: '/graphql',
}));
const graphQLServer = createServer(app);
graphQLServer.listen(GRAPHQL_PORT, () => console.log(`GraphQL Server is now running on http://localhost:${GRAPHQL_PORT}/graphql`));
```

reports an error `Cannot GET /`

I've read that maybe the `createServer` function is deprecated, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Where are you seeing this error? If you're going to `http://localhost:8000/` and seeing that in your browser then this is expected behavior -- you've only defined routes for `/graphql` and `/graphiql`, not `/`.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use express, you have to be explicitly define the routes used by your application. For example, if you define a route with `app.get('/hello', handler)` then any GET requests to `localhost/hello` will get **routed** to that handler. It can then execute whatever logic and return a response, be that a JSON object, a webpage, etc.

Express will only handle the routes you've defined in this way. So if you've only defined a route for requests that GET `/hello`, it will not know how to GET `/foo`, or GET your root path `/`. If you wanted to implement a way to POST or PUT to `/hello`, that would need to be a different route as well.

You can use `app.use` in a similar way to implement middleware in your application. While middleware typically takes your request, manipulates it and pass it on, it can also be used to break up your routing logic.

In the case of GraphQL, requests are typically made using the POST method, but the specification does allow for both POST **and** GET requests. To do this, we would have to define handlers for both `app.get('/graphql')` and `app.post('/graphql')`. The `graphqlExpress` middleware you're importing and using conveniently does that for you.

So with your set up, you've created some routes that allow you to POST to and GET from `localhost:8000/graphql`. You've also enabled GraphiQL on `localhost:8000/graphiql`. If you don't see any errors in the console when you start your server, you should be able to navigate to the GraphiQL page at `localhost:8000/graphiql` and play around with your schema.

**But these are the only routes you've set up on your server.** If you attempt to navigate anywhere else, like the root at `localhost:8000/`, express won't know how to handle that request and you will see the error you reported.

Answer (score 0):

Use `app.listen(port, function(){console.log('server started')});` instead of createServer(app).

Comment: Then your problem is entirely on graphql which I have not used. No route is registered on your express app for /